# How to insert admin-label of color-attribute while placing order in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to map color-code with actual value of color so what I did is just set color-code value into "Default Store Value" and actual color-name in admin-label.

Like in color attribute option-value, I have added "blue" for "Admin" and "#0000FF" to
"Default Store View"

Now, when I place any order the entry of color-code placed inside the order and displayed on invoice and also sent via mail to the customer.

How can I solve this problem or How can I change color-code value with admin-label value of color-code while placing the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install extension for proper mapping of color code with color names.
Many Extensions are available at magento connect.

Comment: It is true. Extensions are developed by testing on every versions, so it is the last option I used because of deadline. But still if any type of guidelines regarding how t develop extension then please share.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can get admin label for an attribute for a product

```
$attrbute_code = 'color';
$_attribute= $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attrbute_code);
$_options= $_attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach($_options as $option)
      if ($option['value'] == $product->getData($attrbute_code))
        echo  $option['label'];
```

and for Storeview label

```
echo $product->getAttributeText($attribute_code);
```

Comment: This is fine, I can get admin-label using this method but when client places any order then in database, color-code is entered and it also reflects in invoice and e-mail which is sent to client for new order.
Do you know how to counter this problem?

Comment: ok. Now I got your quetion. Just confirm me that you are purchasing configurable product on basis of some attribute and that attribute's label you want from admin in your Order

Comment: Yes I am using configurable product, and in option value of color-attribute, I used actual color-name in "Admin" and color-code in "Default store view" in admin-panel.